# Good EOF byte for network communication

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, eof

I'm writing a c# library for turn key network communication. I'm looking for a non-ambiguous byte that I can use in my library to indicate end of block of data. The goal would be to be able to send any file or string regardless of format. Would the Null character do it such that it won't screw with the TCP connection and no file or string should ever have it within it's data.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: BTW both client and server are apart of my library so it doesn't need to comply with any other standard.

After Answers:
I'm going to make an array of X bytes then use the last byte to indicate if and where the EOF is located in the block of (X-1) bytes.

Comment: "and no file or string should ever have it within it's data" ... and the reasons for that would be...?

Comment: There is no byte that no file will ever contain. You could length-prefix your data instead..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You ask the impossible**

"Any file or string" can include any byte sequence.

That makes it entirely impossible to find an EOF byte.  Even a byte sequence is not guaranteed to work in all cases.

**Solution: File size known in advance**

Send the length of data to follow as part of the communication header.

**Solution: File size unknown / streaming**

Define a data structure that includes a marker whether more data is to follow separate from the file contents.

Comment: @"Eric J." All files and strings end with '/0' as their sentinel value so why can't I since that is infact reserved for such use

Comment: +1. @user1580785, It is unclear why do you think that '\0' can't be part of string (not even speaking about file). Try to see what following evaluates to: `"\0\0".Length`.

Comment: @"Alexei Levenkov" Well after leaning C I guess it wasn't made clear that C# uses a different mechanism for its end of string. If you know I would love to know.

Comment: @user1580785: C uses a nul character to mark the end of a *string*, not to mark the end of arbitrary binary data.  Binary data will in general have all bytes with equal probability.

Comment: @"Eric J." yeah that was my answer to the previous comment and I thought that no file would ever have '/0' but my communication with Coeffect corrected me on that so that point was moot anyways

Answer (score 4):

This seems impossible by definition. A single byte that always signals an end of data? But you want to be able to send any file, which could include a binary file that can include any byte. So clearly you'd need a restriction on the contents of the file to be able to reserve one byte for an EOF.

Like Blorgbeard mentioned in the comments, look at sending over your data's length first. This can be an agreed upon number of bytes that signal how long the payload of the data will be. Your program reads this meta data to know how many bytes it should expect to read before the end of the packet.

Comment: All files and strings end with '/0' as their sentinel value so why can't I since that is infact reserved for such use

Comment: @user1580785 That works in some cases, where the byte is reserved. But not all data structures work like that. The null character is literally just the character with value 0. In a binary file, in an array of bytes, in an integer.. that 0 byte can exist.

Comment: In a binary file if it has '\0' anywhere not at the end the rest of the file is essentially in white space on the HDD since the file alloc table doesn't keep a length. Secondly I'm not to concerned with the other instances you posed, I'm going to be the only one using it anyways so I'll be aware in those rare cases.

Comment: @user1580785 That's simply not true. I literally just wrote 1000000 bytes to a file, 0-255 repeating, and it quite clearly does not terminate the file. The null character can't be displayed, but it can exist in a file.

Comment: Hmm well thanks for doing that for me. In a forensics class I learned about the EOF thing, I guess I need to go and reread that because I know modern File Systems don't have the length of file in their File Allocation Table's. Just out of curiosity do you know what they use for sentinel values or am I wrong on this fundamentally.

Comment: Honestly, it's been a while since I took system programming so I can't really remember for sure. I'm positive that somewhere in the metadata that accompanies every file there's a length somewhere. Otherwise every time you opened notepad you'd see a ton of crap at the end.

Comment: DOS text files used to consider Control-Z to be End of File.  There is a similar end-of-input marker in Unix (can't recall what it is) that is only valid for text streams.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is to 'escape' any terminating char in the body of the data, eg. if using NUL as terminator, replace any NUL with [ESC][SOH] and any [ESC] with [ESC][ESC].

This works for any streaming data of any length, but it does mean iterating the data at both ends.